# How to fetch a limited number of related models?

Tags: swift-data, swift-data-relationship

With the ParentModel, I would like to fetch *only* the most recent 7 ChildModels.

What's the best way to do this?

#### Relationship

Say you have a relationship set up like so:

```
@Model
class ParentModel {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \ChildModel.parent)
    var children: [ChildModel] = []
    
    init(name: String, children: [ChildModel] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
}

@Model
class ChildModel {
    var date: Date
    var value: Double
    var parent: ParentModel?
    
    init(date: Date, value: Double, parent: ParentModel? = nil) {
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

#### Example

This is what I would like to achieve, just 7 related rows. So if there were 100 child rows, I would only want the 7 most recent ones.

[image: Animation of screen going from parent to children]

#### GitHub Repo

If you want a working project to try and find or test your solution, I have it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/bigmountainstudio/FetchChildrenByParentModel).

Comment: What does partial related means here, is this different from the previous question where you only wanted child objects for a specific parent? If it is the same then I don’t think you can do it with a Predicate since they don’t seem to work well with relationships.

Comment: Yeah, Ok, that's what I thought. I was hoping there was something I was missing. I did find a way to do it but I hoped there was a more "native" way. The workaround solution is in the GitHub where I had to use a custom FetchDescriptor (sort descending, fetchLimit of 7).

Comment: The issues with trying to use relationships in any way in a Predicate macro is quite frustrating so I hope this is something that is high on Apple's to do list.